# Web SVN Browser that shows DocX Files

Tags: svn, browser, ms-word, word-2007

So I have a tonne of Microsoft Word 2007 files in an svn repo atm as a I take notes on a netbook at school.

Does anyone know of a web based SVN browser that will show Microsoft Word 2007 files. Assembla's source viewer doesn't, and I don;t think trac does either. I'd like a web based browser as I would like to be able to distribute this link to those who don't know how to use SVN.

I know there was on based on Java and Flash, can't remember at the moment though.

Does anyone know one thats preferablly written in aspx or PHP?

P.S.: If anyone knows a Git browser that'd do just as well.

Comment: I think there is no server side product that can natively show (= parse + render) these files, but it should be relatively easy to embed them in an `<object>` or something if you have Word 2007 installed on your machine. Is that the case?

Comment: I do have Word 2007 installed as I am the one composing the documents, but i'd like to be able to have anyone who goes to the browser be able to view the files with ease without having Word 2007 installed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to have a good result from this.

you'd be much better off saving your files in ODF format, there are plenty of [plugins](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/odf-viewer/) and [viewers](http://www.oxygenxml.com/open_document_odf.html) available for that format, whereas only Microsoft has a docx viewer (and I think that's going to requre Office installed on the clients).

Office 2010 supports ODF fully, so there's no reason to hold off using it because its non-Microsoft.

Comment: When I went to save the file as an ODF, All I could find was Open Document Text. Is there a difference between OpenDocument Text and OpenDocument Format?